# How to fix TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('<U10'),)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to build a simple song artist recommendation system in Python using cosine similarity algorithms. The dataset that I'm using is the last.fm dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/neferfufi/lastfm

I've been following the blog at https://www.benfrederickson.com/distance-metrics/
and I've tried to write similar code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import zeros
from collections import defaultdict
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import keras
from keras.layers import dot
url_data = pd.read_csv("stuff.tsv", 
                         usecols=[0, 2, 3], 
                         names=['user', 'artist', 'plays'])

userids = defaultdict(lambda: len(userids))
url_data['userid'] = url_data['user'].map(userids.__getitem__)

artists = dict((artist, csr_matrix(
                (group['plays'], (zeros(len(group)), group['userid'])),
                shape=[1, len(userids)]))
        for artist, group in data.groupby('artist'))

SMOOTHING = 20

def newSmoothcosine(a, b):
    overlap = dot(binarize(a), binarize(b).T)[0, 0]

    # smooth cosine by discounting by set intersection
    return (overlap / (SMOOTHING + overlap)) * cosine(a, b)

def binarize(artist):
    ret = csr_matrix(artist)
    ret.data  = ones(len(artist.data))
    return ret

print(newSmoothcosine('Kanye West', 'Jay-Z'))
```

I expect it to return the smoothed cosine of the angle between the two artists, but instead I get

```py
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('<U10'),)
```

Please help out!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution i dont it will work or not but you can try using lambda which convert the dtype float 
`df.apply(lambda x: x.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')).astype('float')`

Comment: Where do I use this code? Could you point me to the line? Sorry, I'm a newbie at machine learning.